# Motivation to run full nodes

Tags: bitcoind

I'm sorry if I ask a stupid question. Bitcoin network was conceived by Satoshi Nakamoto as a decentralized network, but now we are seeing the full centralization of nodes in the United States.
The user lacks motivation for hosting the full node as it requires financial costs but it does not pay off.
I have a question. Does the bitcoin network protocol display address when requesting a [useragent](https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/?q=Kazakhstan). Now we can see only the version and ip address. To anyone could donate a certain amount of coins for those who start a full node in the network.
The [ideal](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-nodes-need/) option proposed by the bitcoin core developer Jeff Garzik  would be to make a commission for that unit is now fully take miners to share with all the owners of the full nodes.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: A correction in your question: the article doesn't say it is Garzik who is proposing to reward people who run a full node, it just says it is "an idea that has been floated".

Comment: 'now we are seeing the full centralization of nodes in the United States.' That's a huge exaggeration.

Comment: Incentivising nodes is an issue. But it depends on how that is handled. Are there other duties that a machine running a full node could perform, and, for example, benefit from by the inclusion of a small payment?

Comment: From a pragmatic standpoint nodes *are* an issue in the Bitcoin network. There is a lot of centralisation since CPU mining was traded for ASICs. Personally, I run a node because I want to learn how the network works. There is incentives to run nodes, nonfinancial incentives too, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but: No, Bitcoin nodes do not announce their own Bitcoin addresses as part of the network protocol.

One could imagine modifying the protocol so that they did, but it would raise anonymity concerns: currently, by design, it is difficult to match an address with its owner's IP address.  If you knew at least one address that belonged to a particular node, you  might be able to look at other transactions in the block chain and deduce other addresses belonging to that node.  And ISPs usually have records that determine the identity of a user from their IP address.